# How to use regular expression in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table with a column 'DESCRIPTION'.
I would like retrieve, by a regular expression, only rows with at least one lower case character.

I have tried

```
select * from  MYTABLE t 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (t.DESCRIPTION, '[a-z]');
```

but the result is equal to

```
select * from  MYTABLE t
```

Comment: are you sure? This should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to explicily force a case sensitive comparison:

```
select *
from  MYTABLE t 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (t.DESCRIPTION, '[a-z]', 'c')
```

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm):

> If you omit match_parameter, then:
>
> The default case sensitivity is determined by the value of the
>   NLS_SORT parameter